# Printing the factors of a certain integer in a specific format

Tags: java

I would like to know how you would print the factors of any integer in the format (sum = factor + factor... = sum > num) using the for loop's i as factors.
i, once again, am a student, please go easy this code is stressing me out. (in the code provided, we already found the factors, we want it to be printed in a specific format)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Abundant {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int output = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter an integer:");
        num = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The factors of " +num + " are:");
        for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re currently just printing i in each loop. Create a variable and work out your sum, then print said variable.

Comment: @notyou I already have a way to find the sum. Let's say we input the integer "36", 36 has a number of factors (excluding itself). I would like to have a statement print "36 is an abundant number because 36 = factor + factor +... = 55 > 36"

Answer (score 2):

First you need to *work out* what the factors are.

So ask yourself these questions:

1. How do I test if a number F is a factor of another number N?   In other words, what is the mathematical definition of a factor?  Hint: [reference](https://www.britannica.com/science/factor-mathematics).
2. Given I know how to test if one number is a factor of another, how do I find all of the factors?  Hint: think of a loop.

Armed with the answers to those questions, it is a small step to writing a program that does this.

---

Actually ... I have a feeling that you might be using the word "factor" to mean something other than a mathematical factor.  If so, we need a much clearer explanation in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Java Streaming API** to the rescue:

```
int num = ...
String factors = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, num) // all numbers from 1..num, inclusive
    .filter(i -> num % i == 0) // only those by which num can be divided
    .mapToObj(String::valueOf) // as strings
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" + ")); // concatenated with ' + '

System.out.printf("Factors of %d: %s", num, factors);
```

Example output for num = 96:

> Factors of 96: 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 12 + 16 + 24 + 32 + 48 + 96

**Old-school way:**
when concatenating, you need to memorize a state (all factors except the first have a ' + ' prepended):

```
boolean first = true;
System.out.printf("Factors of %d: ", num);
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        if (!first) {
            System.out.print(" + ");
        }
        first = false;
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

Certainly not as elegant as the stream solution though.